# Find cutoff frequency of a common emmitter amplifier

Tags: amplifier, simulation, bode-plot, cutoff-frequency

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXClDX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need to find the cutoff frequency of this common emmitter amplifier. Is it possible to simulate a bode plot?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: What simulator do you use?

Comment: **Real** engineers first estimate what the gain plot would look like from a few hand calculations and then **confirm** that with a simulator. But if you don't do that, expect that there will come a day when the simulator will **lie** to you.

Comment: Could you help me doing this few hand calculations, please?

Comment: It is explained in many textbooks about analog design how to do these hand calculations. I suggest you consult such a book.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to specify `V2` as the input element and node `out` as the output.

Then you can perform a `Frequency Domain` simulation.

[image]

Comment: Which software do you use?

Comment: The same software you just used to enter the schematic into your question. Did you not see the "Simulate" button at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Below your schematic is a link `simulate this circuit`.